# MySQL Match by Multiple Columns from Select in WHERE NOT IN Clause

Tags: mysql, where-in

**Problem:**

I have a list of rooms that belong to different buildings. For example:

```
Laundry Room, Building A, 1st Floor
Apartment 102, Building A, 1st Floor
Laundry Room, Building B, 1st Floor
Office Suite 1, Building B, 2nd Floor
```

I routinely have to check a spreadsheet to see if a room/building combination I've been sent is already in the database or needs to be created.

**What I've Tried:**

I've created a script that populates the following temporary table with the data from the spreadsheet. The temp table is being populated correctly:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_test
(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, room_name VARCHAR(45), 
building_name VARCHAR(45), floor_name VARCHAR (45), PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Then, I wrote this query to find everything from the temporary that is NOT IN the production database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT room_name, building_name, floor_name
FROM room_test
WHERE room_name, building_name, floor_name NOT IN
(
SELECT r.name, b.name, f.name
FROM room AS r
JOIN building AS b ON r.building_id = b.id
JOIN floor AS f ON r.floor_id = f.id
);
```

I'm getting errors back.

I also tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT room_name, building_name, floor_name
FROM room_test
WHERE room_name NOT IN
(
SELECT r.name
FROM room AS r
JOIN building AS b ON r.building_id = b.id
JOIN floor AS f ON r.floor_id = f.id
GROUP BY r.name, b.name, f.name
);
```

But the output was incomplete.

**Output I Expect**

I'm trying to get a list of every unique pairing of room name, building name, and floor name from the temporary table that isn't in the production database.

The 3-part matching is critical because you can have a room with the same name on the same floor in two different buildings, or two rooms with the same name in the same building but on different floors.

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing `WHERE room_name, building_name, floor_name NOT IN` to `WHERE (room_name, building_name, floor_name) NOT IN`

Comment: I tried it, it did not work.

Comment: Do you still get errors back, or are your results not what you expected?